# Unable to launch Chrome driver in selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, driver

I get the following error while launching chrome driver. Any suggestions?

```
package packag;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459     (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 26665
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:    unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
>        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459    (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.2
>   x86_64)     (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 754 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15    17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'Vishak', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Windows 8',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>     at packag.Demo2.main(Demo2.java:11)

Comment: It can't find Google Chrome, not the chrome driver. Make sure you have google chrome installed in the location the driver is expecting.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? - Having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Install Chrome on the machine running your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser incompatibility. Either you need to update ChromeDriver or vice verse. I would recommend installing updated versions of both on safer side.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest **chromedriver.exe** and placed it under **C:/chromedriver.exe** directory.

If not please download the same from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and place it in specified directory.

Comment: it just needs to be somewhere on your PATH

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue by placing the wrong executable. so you can

- download the correct executable for your platform.
- you may want to place the driver executable somewhere other than the "c" drive. 
  may be documents directory for your user, or create a directory in your project 
  and refer from there.

Comment: It works even if I place it under c drive or other drives so there is no need of second point

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar : agreed, 2nd point can help in some cases where directories/files may have permission issues for some user profiles. so for those cases changing directories/permissions help.

Comment: Permission issues comes into picture when you have to write or modify any file which system at times won't allow but you can read / access  data from any drive